# Need to populate a custom sequence index in a column based on values in other column for flow with Data Weave in Mulesoft

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I need to write a sequence/index in a column based on values in another column. **Please find sample below to explain my request :**
Here, I need to generate index values in the customindex column based on the values in color column.. so basically if there are 4 rows with red in column, then it should index the rows as 1,2,3,4 and then when its 2 rows with blue as a value, it should again index from 1 -> 1,2.

Input data:

```
[
  {
    "Type": "Header",
    "Color": "Red",
    "Customindex": "",
"code":"H1",
    },
  {
    "Type": "Header",
    "Color": "Blue",
    "Customindex": "",
"code":"H2",
    },

  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Red",
    "Customindex": "",
"code":"L1",
    },

  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Red",
    "Customindex": "",
"code":"L1"
    },

  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Blue",
    "Customindex": "",
"code":"L2"
    },

  {
    "Type": "Header",
    "Color": "Yellow",
    "Customindex": "",
"code":"H3"
    },

  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Yellow",
    "Customindex": "",
"code":"L3"
    },
  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Yellow",
    "Customindex": "",
"code":"L3"
    },
  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Blue",
    "Customindex": "",
   "code":"L2"
    }
]
```

here is the transformation that i need help with:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var TM = flatten(payload map ((item, index) ->
[{
"Type":payload.type, //HEADER VALUES
"Color":"",
"Customindex":"",
"code":"",
}]++
[{
"Type":payload.type,// LINE ITEM VALUES
"Color":payload.color,
"Customindex":index,//need the index sequence to only count similar colors
"code":"",
}]))
---
(((TM distinctBy $ ... filters and groupings
```

**Sample data with details (THIS IS THE EXPECTED OUTPUT - should work only for line items):**
[image]

Comment: I see there is a similar question asked and was wondering if you made any progress on the script provided there. If so could you post what your most recent script looks like ?

Comment: Hi @Salim, your solution did work but i used my original approach with orderby and distinctby for my soution. I added the payload in a variable before splitting and it worked somehow(It wasnt working if i dont use a variable). My flow logic : Split every record to header and footer, order all rows by a reference field.. once the rows were ordered, use distictby header so it ends up with one header and corresponding line items. Used a piece of your code to join the arrays v.i.z "]++[" and it helped.

Comment: maybe post your most recent script here?

Comment: @SalimKhan its the same as posted in the main question above. if you can see in the variable TM, , every record is split into two - 1 marked as header with common fields values, 1 with line item which includes columns with unique values. So for records -> its 10 header and 10 line items. then i use distinct by to remove duplicate headers. and then order by the reference fields for both header and line items so all rows are grouped. I have used an extra input column in payload to build a consistent reference.
((TM distinctBy $.integrationid) orderBy $.integrationidl)

Comment: dear @SalimKhan if you are referring to the solution by george, then it does work but it is actually building an extra column instead of updating the existing column. here is 
the solution that he provided :  var vs2idx = data.*Color distinctBy $ 
             reduce (e,acc={}) -> acc ++ {(e): 1}

---

(data reduce (row,acc={env: vs2idx, result: []}) -> do {
    var r = acc.result + {(row - "Customindex"), Customindex: acc.env[row.Color]}
    var e = {(acc.env - row.Color), (row.Color): acc.env[row.Color]+1}
    ---
    {env: e, result: r}
}).result

Comment: Avoid asking the same exact question twice @Vineetz.  When I asked you to ask a new question--it was the question related to the ordering of fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

Input:

```
[
    {
        "Type": "Header",
        "Color": "Red",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "H1"
    }, {
        "Type": "Header",
        "Color": "Blue",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "H2"
    },
        {
        "Type": "Header",
        "Color": "Green",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "H4"
    },
    {
        "Type": "LineItem",
        "Color": "Green",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "L4"
    },
    {
        "Type": "LineItem",
        "Color": "Green",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "L4"
    },
    {
        "Type": "LineItem",
        "Color": "Green",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "L4"
    },
    {
        "Type": "LineItem",
        "Color": "Green",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "L4"
    },
    {
        "Type": "LineItem",
        "Color": "Red",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "L1"
    },
    {
        "Type": "LineItem",
        "Color": "Red",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "L1"
    },
    {
        "Type": "LineItem",
        "Color": "Blue",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "L2"
    },
    {
        "Type": "Header",
        "Color": "Yellow",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "H3"
    },
    {
        "Type": "LineItem",
        "Color": "Yellow",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "L3"
    }, {
        "Type": "LineItem",
        "Color": "Yellow",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "L3"
    }, {
        "Type": "LineItem",
        "Color": "Blue",
        "Customindex": "",
        "code": "L2"
        
    }
]
```

Script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
fun buildHeader(code) = {
     'Type': 'Header',
      "Color": "",
      "CustomIndex":"",
      "Code":code
}

fun buildFirstLineItem(code,color,ci) = {
     'Type': 'LineItem',
      "Color": color,
      "CustomIndex":ci,
      "Code":code replace ("H") with ("L")
}
---

flatten(payload orderBy $.code groupBy $.Color mapObject {
    a: flatten($ map (
    if($.'Type' == 'Header')
     [buildHeader($.code)] + [buildFirstLineItem($.code,$.Color,(($$)+1))][0]
     else
      {
      'Type': "LineItem",
      "Color": $.Color,
      "CustomIndex": (($$)+1),
      "Code":$.code 
      }
      ))
 }pluck($))
```

Output:

```
Type,Color,CustomIndex,Code
Type,Color,CustomIndex,Code
Header,,,H1
LineItem,Red,1,L1
LineItem,Red,2,L1
LineItem,Red,3,L1
Header,,,H2
LineItem,Blue,1,L2
LineItem,Blue,2,L2
LineItem,Blue,3,L2
Header,,,H3
LineItem,Yellow,1,L3
LineItem,Yellow,2,L3
LineItem,Yellow,3,L3
Header,,,H4
LineItem,Green,1,L4
LineItem,Green,2,L4
LineItem,Green,3,L4
LineItem,Green,4,L4
LineItem,Green,5,L4
```